# Is there any gem in rails for http://twittercounter.com/

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any gem in rails for http://twittercounter.com/. i have checked the https://github.com/zigotto/twittercounter but it seems like it's very old and not maintained any more. I want to fetch the top 100 twitter users from the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at their [API documentation](http://twittercounter.com/pages/api) and doing a quick comparison to the gem you mentioned, it doesn't seem like there were any updates at first glance. That being said, it's an API with only one endpoint and you have to be (what seems like) manually added to get an API key [on this page](http://twittercounter.com/pages/api-signup/), so I'd just write your own wrapper for it using [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or something similar.

Comment: i am thinking in the same way. thanks for your help.